# How can you send an array of numbers from as3 to php?

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3

Here's what I'm working with:

```
var stats:Array = ["11", "22", "33"];
        
        create();
        
        function create():void 
        {
            var sender:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
            var myVar:URLVariables = new URLVariables;
                
                myVar.stats = stats;
            var website:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.roomrecess.com/MQFiles/createChar.php");
                website.data = myVar;
                sender.load(website);
            sender.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendComplete);  
                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty self explanatory.

```
var vars = new URLVariables();
vars.postFieldName1="dummy1";
vars.postFieldNameA="dummy2";


var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("entry.php");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = vars;

var sender=new URLLoader();
sender.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataSent);
sender.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
sender.load(req);
```

Comment: As a developer who doesn't have any experience with actionscript-3, this answer is not self explanatory and is missing an opportunity to educate me on why this is the most appropriate way to perform this task.  Are there any relevant links to documentation that you recommend?  Are there any techniques that you explicitly do not recommend?